# Find the rotated images in folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, jpeg

> A folder contains 134944 files and 6919 folders.

They are graduation albums contains scenes and avtars.

The jpg images were generate by the **scansnap sv600** and then manually slice, copy, paste, rename, group into the folders.

> most  avtar image's height > width.
> [image]

The above pictures are all in correct direction.

What can I do to find the incorrect images in win7 ?

Comment: You can select images based on rotation via the **Orientation** column/search criteria. But if you want to akutomate the comparison of Height vs. Width, you'd need a script or 3rd-party tool.

Comment: Thank you Keith Miller

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click column field.
Select Orientation.

[image]

Comment: Ignore my comment all this time & then post it as your solution???

Comment: I had upvoted your comment last year. Please post your answer in answer zone so I can choose a answer to close this question in my panel. Sorry for the late thank. https://imgur.com/a/qybqPCa

Comment: Cool. Will do so. I had only posted the comment initially in case you were aware of the *`Orientation`* property but it did not meet your needs. It can be discouraging to take the time to compose a detailed answer and the response be,"Forgot to metnion, I already tried that..."!!!